# Pauli matrices decomposition

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

If a matrix $A$ $\in M_{2\times 2}(R)$ can be written like this
$$
A= a\cdot \sigma_{x}+b\cdot \sigma_{z}
$$

all in its standard basis, with $a$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$

which eigenvalues and eigenvectors $A$ has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices#Pauli_vector) provides these formulas for the eigenvectors of a linear combination $\vec a\cdot\vec \sigma$ of the Pauli matrices:

$$
\pmatrix{a_3+|\vec a|\\a_1+\mathrm ia_2}\;,\pmatrix{\mathrm ia_2-a_1\\a_3+|\vec a|}\;.
$$

With your $\vec a=(a,0,b)$, this becomes

$$
\pmatrix{b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\\a}\;,\pmatrix{-a\\b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\;.
$$

Since the eigenvalues are $\pm1$ if $|\vec a|=1$, in this case they are $\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.